# Meteor DOM element not updating upon creation

Tags: meteor

I've just started out in Meteor after reading the Discover Meteor book and have been banging my head against a very annoying problem. I think I'm missing some fundamental knowledge because I just can't seem to figure it out.

The goal is simple. A user get's a ball on account creation and can only move his own ball around. Nothing fancy.
Here's the problem: Upon user creation/first login the user can see his ball and it get's highlighted by the app. But when the arrow keys are used, only other browsers/sessions can see that ball move. If the newly created user refreshes, the ball moves on all browsers/sessions.

The relevant bits of code:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
if (!Meteor.user()) {
    //user logged out
    Session.set('session_ball', null);
} else {
    //user logged in
    var user = Meteor.user(),
        ballId = false;

    //check if the user has a ball yet
    if (!user.profile.hasBall) {
        var ball = {},
            x = parseInt(Math.random() * (500 - 200) + 200, 10),
            y = parseInt(Math.random() * (500 - 200) + 200, 10),
            name = 'ball_' + x + '_' + y;

        ball.name = name;
        ball.x = x;
        ball.y = y;
        ball.owner = user._id;

        Meteor.call('addBall', ball, function (error, id) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('error with adding ball');
            } else {
                //update the user's hasball property
                Meteor.users.update(user._id, {$set: {"profile.hasBall": true}});

                console.log('made new user ball');

            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

and the methods:

```
Meteor.methods({
addBall: function(ball) {
    var user = Meteor.user();

    // ensure the user is logged in
    if (!user || !ball) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(401, 'Oh Balls');
    }

    var ballId = Balls.insert(ball);

    return ballId;
},
moveBall: function(options) {
    if (!options) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(401, 'Oh Balls');
    }

    if (Balls.findOne({_id: options.ballId, owner: Meteor.userId()})) {
        Balls.update(options.ballId, {$inc: {x: options.x, y: options.y}});
    }

    return options.ballId;
}
});
```

Since the code in a meteor project is scattered over a bunch of different files, it's probably easier to see the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/glennnaessens/Meteor-Tryouts/tree/master/appone).

Comment: Wow this is a good one. There is either an extremely subtle race condition happening here that I'm not seeing, or this is a bug in meteor. It has all the earmarks of a bug because the correct data is being published but the cursor just isn't being updated. Also interesting is that it works if you return an array via `return Balls.find().fetch();` instead of a cursor. If you have time, I'd recommend debugging this by removing as much code as possible while still keeping the behavior. You should be left with an obvious mistake or a bug report for the meteor team.

Comment: I'm even more inclined to think this is a bug now because if you run it with the latest release candidate via: `meteor --release 0.8.2-rc1`, I don't see the issue anymore. It may be that this was a known problem, or it was fixed as a consequence of something else.

Comment: @DavidWeldon this is very plausible. 0.8.2 lands with a big chunk of Blaze refactored and cleaned up.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, @David, but the bare essentials of my code still give the problem. Thanks for having a look! I'll just wait until the 0.8.2 release and try some other stuff in the mean time.